# iOS SDK 4.0 for Xcode 4.1 (Lion)?

Tags: ios, ios4

I recently downloaded Xcode 4.1 for Lion with iOS SDK 4.3. Now, whenever I change my Deployment Target to anything older than 4.3, I get hundreds of errors when I try to build my project. This happens even if I'm trying to run it on the 4.3 iOS Simulator, so I don't even need to be actually running it on an older device, I just have to set the older Deployment Target.

Do I need to download a separate SDK in order to allow for older devices? If so, where could I find it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried copying the SDKs from Xcode 4, but it doesn't work.

Other answers suggest [that it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion).

I'm now using a virtual machine with Snow Leopard to test on older devices. (Or real older devices, if you have one)