# Xcode 4 & iOS SDK 4 for Mac OS Lion

Tags: xcode4, ios4, osx-lion

I am able to find the iOS 5 SDK with Xcode 4.2 for Lion. Can I get iOS SDK 4 for Lion OS?
I seen have only the iOS 5 SDK with Xcode 4.2 in Apple developer site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Older iOS SDKs to Xcode 4.1 in Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion)