# iOS Lion - Monotouch and Simulator 4.3

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, osx-lion, ios-simulator

I have the following configuration on Mac OS X 10.7.4:

- MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
- Mono 2.10.9
- Xcode 4.3.3
- Monotouch 5.2.12

I'd like to test my app developed in Monotouch, on iOS 4.3, because on iOS 5.0 works fine. To do that i've tried to install simulator 4.3 in Xcode but when i open Monotouch there is just Simulator 5.0.

I read some information on google and obviously, it advised to install SDK 4.3 but there is no version with this SDK for iOS Lion (the only one on Apple developers website is for Snow Leopard).

I would be interested to know how to install the simulator on my computer.

Comment: Did you see the "Downloads" section in the XCode preferences? Select Components tab and download iOS 4.3 simulator.

Comment: As said i have do that...but when i open Monotouch there isn't the simulator 4.3

Comment: Select the project that contains your  main app.  Then select Project->Active Simulator Target (or something similar to that).  I'm on Windows right now or I would double-check the name.

Comment: Thanks it's a good way to solve my problem...but if i want to install SDK 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hidden but you can still download of Xcode releases from: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Downloading Xcode 4.0 should give you the final SDK for iOS 4.3.

You can install 4.2 and 4.3 (.app) side-to-side on Lion (I have them). This *should* also work for 4.0 and 4.3 since they (like 4.2) ends up in different directories.

Note that you'll need to tell MonoDevelop to switch `Apple SDK` location (and restart MD).

Comment: it's not possible install this kind of version...i've tried to do that but when installer start it say that requires Mac OS X 10.6.6 :-(

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion Xcode 4.1 shipped with iOS 4.3 **and** that version is available for OSX Lion

Comment: In Xcode 4.1 description it's not mentioned the presence of SDK 4.3. Check Download section in Apple Developer

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to install it through Xcode.

XCode > Preferences > Downloads

You should see installs available here. Click the Install button to get it.