# How to build a MonoTouch app with SDK version 4.x (not target earlier version with current sdk)

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I have a legacy application distributed Ad-Hoc that runs on older iPod Touches (running iOS 3.1.3) with a custom connection to rather expensive 3rd party hardware.  Unfortunately my annual renewal of the provisioning profile (which also involved rebuilding with the most recent version of XCode that will compile armv6 (4.5) and the corresponding SDK) seems to have broken the app.

I know that you can set the target platform earlier (and I've done that).  But my problem seems to be specifically related to the SDK.  The hardware these devices interface with is several hundred miles from me so testing is very difficult.

My first set of problems were related to deprecation of the TouchID APIs, but I've worked around that problem.  Unforatunately, I still have crashes and they are proving very elusive to debug.

The simplest solution for me would be to just rebuild against the older SDK (4.x).  Is this possible?  To make matters worse my Mac is running 10.8.4--so there's a limit to how far back I can get XCode working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by renaming my current version of XCode to something else, downloading and installing XCode 4.4 something from the developer site.  Then I downloaded an earlier version yet and used the techniques described in this post:

[Adding Older iOS SDKs to Xcode 4.1 in Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion)

To extract the older SDKs.  I was then able to copy these SDKs into XCode 4.4 (as described in the post).  Now I was able to build using older versions of the SDK.