# How to install iOS SDK on XCode 3.2.6

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have Mac 10.6.8 and XCode already installed with version 3.2.6

I need the development environment to develop some apps but I don't have the iOS SDK.

I've seen that I would need to update xcode in order to get the iOS SDK, but when I go to the appstore and ask for the installation file it says me that i need a version 10.8 or later.

Is there a way to get the iOS SDK without the updating of xcode?

Comment: If you plan on creating an iOS app for the app store you need Xcode 5.x. If you need to test on a device with iOS 7.1 your need Xcode 5.1. Developing with Xcode 3 is pointless. It is far too old and there have been far too many changes to waste your time with such an old version.

Comment: So obviously you have some answers here but why don't you want to update?  Mavericks is free so unless you're running unsupported hardware then why not update?  There are so many advantages to using the new versions of xcode so you'd be wasting your time using 3.2.6 to be perfectly honest.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy earlier version of xcode, 4.2 should be fine. You can download it from developer.apple.com in case you're a registered developer. Otherwise, it's up to you to find another opportunity.

Comment: I think Apple have already deprecated (or are deprecating) pre-Xcode 5 submissions to the app store. I'm not 100%, but I feel like I got an e-mail from Apple about this.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to get the iOS SDK without the updating of Xcode?**

Yes. Just review the highly cited answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783308/adding-older-ios-sdks-to-xcode-4-1-in-lion)

The basic idea is to download the .dmg for Xcode with one of the SDK's that you would like to build against.

Then:

1. Mount the .dmg as if you are preparing to install
2. Right-click the .dmg and view inside the package
3. Navigate to the folder
   Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
4. Copy the contents of the target SDK folder and paste them into the relative path on your installed Xcode

You can download many different versions of Xcode (and their corresponding SDK's from this developer only [website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#))

Note: You can and should use the latest Xcode version available to you. For your OS version that is Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard.

Recommendation:

Check to see if you can update your OS based on age of your machine (and do so if possible).

[image: Xcode 4.2]